# How to converte this code from C to Mips?

Tags: c, mips, microprocessors

Can anyone help me convert this C code into Mips?
I really have no idea. Anything will help. Thanks!

```
  int aplica(int (*f)(int), int x)
  {
    return (*f)(x);
  }

  int f1(int y){return y+y;}
  int f2(int y){return y*y;}
  int f3(int y){return -y;}
  
  int (*vf[])={f1, f2, f3}, v[3];

  void main()
  {
    register int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;++i) v[i]=aplica(vf[i],1+i);
  }
```

Comment: Do we have to convert? I guess we need to cross-compile

Comment: Are you sure this is even valid C code?

Comment: Use a compiler?

Comment: This is what the professor send me. I guess it is a valid code :))

Comment: I really have no idea how to solve this task.

Comment: `int (*f)(int)` declares `f` as a pointer to function taking `int` and returning `int`.

Comment: The expression `(*f)(x)` invokes the function by function pointer, passing `x` as a parameter.  The `*` means dereference of the function pointer, but this can be simplified to `f(x)`, because the `*` is not needed by the C language; in this simplified form, the dereference of the function pointer it is implied.

Comment: This declaration `int (*vf[])={f1, f2, f3}` has a typo; it attempts to declare an array of function pointers, but is missing the function and parameter signature part `(int)`, so it should be `int (*vf[])(int)={f1, f2, f3}`.  (It is declaring an array of pointers to `int` but should be declaring an array of pointer to functions taking `int` and return `int`.)  This is a pretty serious typo.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be homework and it is frowned upon here to give a solution but I can give directions.

Let us repair the code first and add a bit of output (but you should take the time and step through it with a debugger nevertheless):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int aplica(int (*f)(int), int x)
{
   return (*f)(x);
}
static int f1(int y)
{
   return y+y;
}
static int f2(int y)
{
   return y*y;
}
static int f3(int y)
{
   return -y;
}

static int (*vf[3])(int x) = {f1, f2, f3};
static int v[3];

int main(void)
{
   register int i;
   for (i=0; i<3; ++i) {
      v[i]=aplica(vf[i],1+i);
   }
   for (i=0; i<3; ++i) {
      printf("v(%d] = %d, ", i,v[i]);
   }
   putchar('\n');
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile with e.g. `clang -Weverything somips.c -o somips`

It is a simple program that has three simple functions that calls it via function pointers.

Don't get irritated by the array, just do it step by step and start with a single function. Implement a function pointer and call the single function via the function pointer.

```
static int f1(int y)
{
   return y+y;
}
(*fp)(int x) = f1;
```

It looks complicated in C but it still is just a pointer.

To call a function in MIPS you use `jal` "**j**ump **a**nd **l**ink" followed by the name of the function. Hint: you can jump to an address *in* a register with `jalr`. E.g.: `jalr $t0`. Which already is, in a nutshell, your function pointer.

You need to remember (or find it here at Stackoverflow with a little help from Google)

- how to do functions in MIPS
- how to do pointers in MIPS
- how to do arrays (lists) in MIPS

(I tried and C&P'd them into Google with good results)